# Using 'replace' for URLs in Search Results display template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, display-template

I am building a work-around for an issue I've encountered with a product catalog. For some reason, the CSWP and Search Results web part are displaying spaces in the managed metadata term at the end of the friendly URL with '%20' instead of hyphens. I'm admittedly not a developer, but I'm learning my way around...

That said- is there a script that I can add to the Search Results "Item-Default" template that would take 'ctx.CurrentItem.Path' and replace the '%20' with a dash? I've tried piecing together similar scripts from other sites, but the URL never changes. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- in the display template, I repeatedly tried different variations of
`var newPath = ctx.CurrentItem.Path.replace(" "g,"-")`
but nothing was changing.

I found a different snippet that worked perfectly:
`var newPath = ctx.CurrentItem.Path.replace(/\s+/g,"-")`

Now all of the spaces are replaced by hyphens and take me directly to the catalog item page like they should.